# Why is this shell variable not set correctly

Tags: linux, bash

I have a specific user on my linux machine with whom the following command

```
json='[{"date":"2016"}]' && echo ${json}
```

outputs `1` and not `[{"date":"2016"}]`.

With all other users on my machine this works correctly. When I change the command to (omitting the 1)

```
json='[{"date":"206"}]' && echo ${json}
```

it works correct, too.

I am desperately seeking the config difference of this user that leads to this effect. But to be honest, I have no idea.

Any hints out there?

Comment: Maybe better suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com/)?

Comment: Is that user using the same shell as everyone else?

Comment: Quote the json variable, it's being evaluated by the shell. For some reason that someone else can probably explain `[{...}]` is being evaluated to `1`

Comment: @JNevill: Yes, the user uses the same shell.

Comment: Glad you got an answer here - interesting problem, by the way!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Square brackets create a glob expression matching any single character within them.

`[123]` matches a file named `1`, `2`, or `3`; similarly, `[{"date":"2016"}]` matches files named `d`, `a`, `t`, `e`, `:`, `2`, `0`, `1`, `6`, `"`, `{` or `}`.

You aren't noticing it for users who don't have any file thusly named because the default behavior of a glob expression with no matches is no evaluate to itself (though this default can be modified with `shopt -s nullglob`, in which case a glob with no matches evaluates to nothing).

Quote your expansion -- `echo "$json"` -- to avoid this.

---

To reproduce:

```
json='[{"date":"2016"}]'
owd=$PWD
tempdir=$(mktemp -d "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/test.XXXXXX")
cd "$tempdir" && {
  touch 1
  echo "With the bug: "    $json
  echo "Without the bug: " "$json"
}

# cleanup
cd "$owd"
rm -rf "$tempdir"
```

Comment: Yes, but better if you demonstrate this. There has to be a file named '1', and there are no files named any of the other characters in the expansion, as it turns out in this case.

Comment: @kojiro, expanded with a demonstration.